# Client gets stuck in waiting response from server

Tags: python, c, sockets

I am currently writing a server in C and a client in Python. Below is the code for the server and client.
**# server.c**

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 3000
#define BUFFSIZE 256
#define SOCKETERROR (-1)
#define SERVER_BACKLOG 1

int check(int exp, const char *msg) {
  if (exp == SOCKETERROR) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
  }
  return exp;
}

int main() {

  int server_socket, client_socket, addr_size;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

  check((server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)),
        "Failed to create socket");

  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

  check(bind(server_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
             sizeof(server_addr)),
        "Failed to bind!");

  check(listen(server_socket, SERVER_BACKLOG), "Failed to listen!");

  while (1) {
    printf("Waiting for connections\n");
    addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    check(client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,
                                 (socklen_t *)&addr_size),
          "Failed to connect to client socket");
    printf("Connected to the client\n");

    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    bzero(buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    size_t bytes_read = 0;

    int msgsize = 0;

    while (1) {

      bytes_read = read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
      printf("The number of byte was read is %lu\n", bytes_read);
      if (bytes_read <= 0) { break; }
    }
    // }

    printf("The message from client is %s", buffer);
    write(client_socket, "I got your message", 18);
    close(client_socket);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**#client.py**

```
import socket

server_addr = '127.0.0.1'
server_port = 3000

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    client_socket.connect((server_addr, server_port))
    message = b"Hello world! This is a message from client"
    client_socket.sendall(message)
    data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)

except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print("Connection to the server refused")

finally:
    client_socket.close()
```

The client will send a simple message to the server. I expect that the server will read the data that is sent from the client and send back the message to the client. The problem arises when the server reads the data that is sent from the client.

```
while (1) {
    bytes_read = read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
    printf("The number of bytes read is %lu\n", bytes_read);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) { 
        break; 
    }
}
```

If I put the while loop to read the data that is sent to the server, it seems that the client gets stuck waiting for the response from the server. I also don't think the while loop was the cause of the issue, since if I forcefully terminate the process on the client, the server goes back to normal and prints out the message that it received from the client. I'm trying to understand why the code behaves the way it does.

Comment: Your server reads from the client, but it never writes anything. This will end up in a deadlock when the server waits for more data to arrive from the client, and the client will wait for data to be received.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your first comment, since I write to the socket after finished reading from the socket in the server code. For the buffer is not contained null terminate, I used `bzero()` to set the buffer to null terminate before writing to it. This is not a safe method, but I think after writing to the buffer, the end of the string is null-terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The server will wait for the client to shutdown the connection for writing, since only then `read` will return 0.

```
while (1) {

  bytes_read = read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
  printf("The number of byte was read is %lu\n", bytes_read);
  if (bytes_read <= 0) { break; }
}
```

The client instead is not shutting down the connection but instead waits for the server to send some data back:

```
client_socket.sendall(message)
data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
```

This results in a deadlock: server waiting for the client and client waiting for the server.

This problem is likely caused by a common misunderstanding that TCP transports "messages". It does not, TCP is only a bidirectional byte stream. And `read` will only signal end (return 0) after the peer stopped writing to the byte stream (shutdown), not after each "message" (which does not exist).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a follow-up question: If the client does not send any further data, does the server continue to wait on that connection? Will the read command wait indefinitely, or does it eventually terminate on its own?

Comment: @DangQuangVinh: unless there is a read timeout set (SO_RCVTIMEO) a socket read will wait until new data come in, the peer closes the connection or at least shuts down the writing direction.